# Google Plus image Caching

Tags: javascript, html, image, caching, google-plus

I have a webapp that shows Google+ profile pics of various users.
I just came across an error saying '403 rate limit exceeded' and all the images on my webapp are broken.

Note : I noticed that after a few mins this error goes away.

I don't want users to get a broken images when they visit my webapp, so I was thinking to cache those images in HTML5 localstorage, but I'm not sure if it will help.

Suppose I have an image (Note : I have several such images of different users on my webpage)

```
<img src='/url_to_g+_dp'>
. . . other html . . .
<script>JavaScript</script>
```

and some JavaScript that saves the image to localstorage after it finishes loading. The next time user visits the page, the browser will make a request to '/url_to_g+_dp' before  JavaScript gets a chance to check if the image exists in localstorage. This way, even if I implement caching it won't help me to a large extent.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Suggestions are welcome.

Cheers :)

Comment: Where are you actually getting the 403? From the http request for the actual image file? Or in an api request to get the image URL? Somewhere else?

Comment: from the http request for the actual image file

Answer (score 0):

Caching will help, but not the way you propose it. Dont use an img tag, use something else and set dom properties so you know what to load. Later find all such elements and replace them with imeg, with the appropiate url (cached or uncached)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the bandwidth limit is for viewing Google + profile images on an external domain but your method would at least seem to buy you some time before running into the 403 error.

You will probably want to solely use javascript to load your image data.

first give your image an id and empty out the src attribute:

```
<img id='profile-img' src=''>
```

then always load the image with your javascript.  (I don't believe localStorage will allow you to store binary data so you will want to base64 encode your image before storing it):

```
<script>
    var profile_img;

    if ( localStorage.getItem('profile_image')) {
         //if the image is already locally stored then use it
         profile_img = localStorage.getItem('profile_image');
    }
    else {
         //grab the google + profile image and store it locally
         profile_img = [base64 encoded image from google +]; //i'm not sure off of the top of my head how you would want to go about accomplishing this.
         localStorage.setItem('profile_image',profile_img);
    }

    document.getElementById("profile-img").src='data:image/png;base64,' + profile_img;
</script>
```